# How do I use a timer and or a do while loop to make labels show up for a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, loops, timer, enums

So basically what I have right now is a form with hidden labels in it, and I'm using cases along with a simple counter (counting the clicks on a picturebox) to move through the cases. What I need to happen is when I get to case 2 I need the labels to pop up for a certain amount of time (1 second or so) and the goal is for the user to memorize 2 of those and put it in a text box. I'm just confused on how I use a timer or a do while loop to make the labels only pop up for a certain amount of time as with cases it only checks it once right when it's clicked. Also I'm using enums to store the "Answers" but I'm not 100 percent sure how to crosscheck what the user inputs and what the enum is. Sorry if it's a really easy answer, I'm quite new to C#, and especially loops and enums. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Cases

```
private void pbMummy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;

        switch (counter)
        {
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("Help me! I lost my passwords. Can you try and just get 2 of them?");
                break;

            case 2:

                    lblc1.Visible = true;
                    lblc2.Visible = true;
                    lblc3.Visible = true;
                    lblc4.Visible = true;
                    lblc5.Visible = true;

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);

                    lblc1.Visible = false;
                    lblc2.Visible = false;
                    lblc3.Visible = false;
                    lblc4.Visible = false;
                    lblc5.Visible = false;
                  break;

        }
    }
```

Enums

```
 public enum Memorize
    {
        boo92134,
        spooky93,
        grim432,
        fangs9981,
        cobweb439
    }

    public class Mummy
    {
        public Memorize answer { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use async task for this as it's a really simple task:

```
async void ShowLabelForCertainTime( Label label, int milliseconds )
{
   label.Visible = true;
   await Task.Delay( milliseconds ); //Time in milliseconds
   label.Visible = false;
}
```

Just call it in case you want:

```
case 2:
   ShowLabelForCertainTime( lbcl1 );
```

Comment: Is there a reference I need to add? Because async doesn't exist for me.

Comment: Hi @ColeBrowne
Sure! Anything asynchronous, task, threaded, timerized is in System.Threading reference in .NET.
Async tasks work in .NET 4.5 or above

Comment: Yup, there's my problem. It's for school so we're required to use Visual Studio 2010, which is .NET 4 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: not sure why but I have been working with "buttons" instead of "labels" but the principle is the same

You can use Timers to set your buttons to visible after some time. Use a dictionary so you can retrieve which buttons has launched the event. Here's a code sample just as proof of concept, it needs some refactoring.

```
//run this on the click of the button
int button_id = 1; //or whatever way you want to reference your button
//myButtons[button_id].Visible = false;
var btnTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
btnTimer.Elapsed += myTestClass.HideButton;
btnTimer.Enabled = true;
//keep a reference to that button so you know who the timer belongs to
myTestClass.myTimers[btnTimer] = button_id;
public static class myTestClass
{
    public static Dictionary<System.Timers.Timer, int> myTimers = new Dictionary<System.Timers.Timer, int>();
    public static void HideButton(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer tmr = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
        if(myTimers.ContainsKey(tmr))
        {
            //here you get your reference back to the button to which this timer belongs, you can show/hide it
            //var btn_id =  myButtons[myTimers[tmr]];
            //myButtons[btn_id].Visible = false;
            Console.WriteLine(myTimers[tmr]);
        }
        tmr.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```